# Getting response 200 but not receiving data from android to php

Tags: php, android, json, post, httpurlconnection

I've been doing this for 2 days now, I'm getting response 200 but when I tried to look at my php there's no data from my post code in android, here's my code in android:

```
    URL url = new URL("http:/sample.com/url.php");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

String urlParameters = "uid=123";
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
conn.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");

conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream dStream = conn.getOutputStream();

dStream.write(urlParameters.getBytes());
dStream.flush();
dStream.close();

int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
String output = "Request URL" + url;
output += System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Request Parameters " + urlParameters;
output += System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response Code " + responseCode;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();

while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    responseOutput.append(line);

}
br.close();

output += System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString();

System.out.println(output);
```

and this is simply my php code:

```
$get = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['uid']));

var_dump($get);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

I'm getting a Response Code 200, but I'm not receiving anything in my php file. Please help, I'm a newbie android dev :(

Comment: I am not a expert on php, but might want try [this](http://requestb.in/) to test your android code. Just a thought.